# Why does Nenene put her finger into the barrel?

Tags: read-or-die

In the ending part of the first episode of *R.O.D -The TV-*, a terrorist hijacks the plane Nenene's taking. When the terrorist points his gun to Nenene, Nenene puts her middle finger into the barrel. Why does she do that? What's she trying to do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how commonly this is believed (in Japan or not), the intention is to prevent the bullet from firing properly. That is, she thinks the gun will kind of explode at the end of the muzzle and that the person holding the gun won't be able to shoot because of it.

This was described in Master Keaton as "People somehow believe so due to movies or something."  ([source](https://www.sabaibu.com/comic_anime-survivor/2923/))

Comment: To clarify, the issue here is that a finger won’t form a good enough seal with the barrel to cause the gun to explode. A blocked barrel that’s truly sealed will actually explode, just like a pressure cooker with a blocked pressure relief valve, and is one of the most dangerous possible malfunctions of a firearm.

Comment: I don't think this is really a myth; no one in real life believes this would work. This looks more to be a call back to old cartoons, like how Bugs Bunny does it to Elmer Fudd all the time.